# How do I change the date format from 01-Mar-19 to 2019-03-01 in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, data-analysis

I have  01-Mar-19 but I need it in 2019-03-01 format
I have tried
result = pd.to_datetime(dates)

Comment: try `pd.to_datetime(dates).dt.date()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the input format for the date with the `format` parameter :

```
pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d-%b-%y")
```

Comment: The date type was in string type, I used pd.to_datetime to  2019-03-01 format here is the code I used 
        df["dates"]=pd.to_datetime(df.dates)